# upgrade Xcode to 10.2, build failed

Tags: xcode10.2

After upgrade my Xcode to 10.2, my working project can't build successfully any more, and the following is the error message. cause I'm a newbie at Xcode, I don't know how to fix it.

Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) with runtime iOS 12.2 (12.2 - 16E226) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2

Answer (score 1):

I Encountered a similar situation with Xcode 10.1.

What resolved this for me where following steps:

1. Removing Xcode caches in ~/Library/Caches
2. Puting Xcode in Trash and emptying Trash
3. Downloading and reinstalling Xcode 10.1
4. Reboot

I'd suggest trying to reproduce your issue after each step and then go on if needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, simply run this command in the terminal :

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Comment: Worked for me! Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the Mac fixed the issue for me.

P.S. I also did a "Clean Build Folder" before the reboot, but I don't think that was necessary. If someone who still has the problem can try rebooting without cleaning the build folder and report the result in comments, that might save a step for others.